# parallelstream.anymatch is giving an infinityloop

Tags: java

I have a condition to check a `List<TransactionDetails>` for a value `transactiontype="reversal"`. I used the below line of code:

```
boolean isReversal = transobj.parallelStream()
                             .anyMatch(p -> p.getTransType() 
                                             .name()
                                             .equalsIgnoreCase("reversal"));
```

The above code is giving me an infinite loop. Since I am new to streams, please give me a solution to iterate over `List<TransactionDetails>` for any entry with transactiontype as reversal.

Comment: What is `transobj`?

Comment: This is only an infinite loop if `transobj.parallelStream()` returns an infinite stream. Or if `getTransType().name()` does something infinite.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Eran `transobj` obviously is a `List<TransactionDetails>`